# Git commited everything, but still get error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout

Tags: git

I committed everything. This is my `git status`

```
On branch frontend/leo/auth
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/frontend/leo/auth'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

However, when I try to checkout `dev` branch, I get

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
    frontend/package.json
Please commit your changes or stash them before you switch branches.
Aborting
```

What's happening here?
Why would it ask me to commit when I committed everything?

Answer (score 0):

The problem happened because I was deliberately not tracking `package.json`, following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139762/ignore-files-that-have-already-been-committed-to-a-git-repository/11366713#11366713), which turns out to be **wrong**.

[Here in Git FAQ](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#ignore-tracked-files) it says,

> ##### How do I ignore changes to a tracked file?
>
> **Git doesn’t provide a way
> to do this**. The reason is that if Git needs to overwrite this file,
> such as during a checkout, it doesn’t know whether the changes to the
> file are precious and should be kept, or whether they are irrelevant
> and can safely be destroyed. Therefore, it has to take the safe route
> and always preserve them.
>
> It’s tempting to try to use certain features of `git update-index`,
> namely the assume-unchanged and skip-worktree bits, but these **don’t
> work properly** for this purpose and **shouldn’t be used this way**.

### Correct apporoach:

The [correct approach seems to be the accepted and the most popular answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1139797/7414387) on that SO post.

Comment: That answer is wrong, and the [Git FAQ explains why](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#ignore-tracked-files).

Comment: Edited my answer to improve.